# .htaccess rewrite: Same rule, different location

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Below is a list of some rewrite rules that I want to have for my index page:

```
www.website.com/index.php?page=page1 -> www.website.com/page1
www.website.com/index.php?page=page2 -> www.website.com/page2
```

But I also have a profile page where I want the following rules:

```
www.website.com/profile.php?user=user1 -> www.website.com/user1
www.website.com/profile.php?user=user2 -> www.website.com/user2
```

Both use the same rule, but have different locations. For the index page, there are only 2 possible parameters, `page1` and `page2`, but the profile page's parameters can be anything.

How can I achieve these rewrite rules without doing something like `www.website.com/page/page1` and `www.website.com/user/user1`. I need those exact rules as shown above.

My thought is adding a rule (I'm not sure how) above the user rules to check that the URL doesn't have `page1` or `page2`.

Comment: You should post your actual RewriteRules so we can comment on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only have 2 possible pages, you can get away with something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(page1|page2)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

If you need to redirect externally as well, add these (right below `RewriteEngine On`):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?page=(page1|page2)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+profile\.php\?user=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: What is the reasoning for adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`? Do I need to add that before each new rule?

Comment: @user3871006 you don't need it before every rule. The reasoning is because we're matching against the regex `^([^/]+)$`, which **matches everything without a slash**. That includes "profile.php", "index.php", or any images, scripts, styles, etc. So we must set some conditions to only apply the rule if the requested file doesn't exist, if it does (e.g. like `profile.php`) don't apply the rule.